# php PDO Database hande refuses to return results to queries after, several, succesful calls

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

On my site, we connect to several databases and we have a database handling class that stores the handles in a static array. 99.9% of the time, everything seems to work fine, but every now and then the handle fails silently with no error, and no results are returned. I've been able to recreate the error, then recreate the connection using the following syntax:

```
$db = new PDO("dblib:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_DEFAULT, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
```

Then, it returns results correctly. However, I would prefer to use the same handle for all databases, though, to preserve the extra overhead associated with creating a new connection to a database... or, at least, recreate the connection a minimum number of times.

Is there anyway to evaluate the PDO object to figure out why it's failing, so I can, hopefully, figure out what's going on?

**EDIT:**
I've been looking into this further, and profiled the DB while this error is occuring. PDO stops passing queries to the server after it hits certain queries. (In this case, it was an insert query that tests to see if a record already exists, and if it doesn't then it inserts it).

Make no mistake, this is a horrible and inelligant solution to my problem, but I copied and pasted (and universalized) what resolved it. Basically, when no results are returned, I select 'foo' from the database, if it comes back with no results, I rebuild the connection and attempt to execute the query again. I'm not accepting this as an answer, because it's pretty bad. But this code should better illustrate the problem I am, attempting, to fix.

```
/**
 * Executes a line of sql with PDO.
 *
 * @param string $sql
 * @param array $params
 * @param bool
 * @return array
 */
function execute($sql, $params = array(), $retry = false) {
    //this call gets the database handle that is stored in a static array, so we can reuse the same connection
    $db = db::getDB($this->_database);

    if (get_class($db) != 'PDO') {
        error('database handle wasn\'t created succesfully...');
    }

    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


    try {
        $query = $db->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute($params);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        var_dump($ex);
        return false;
    }

    $results = $query->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(($retry == false) && (!$results)){
        $newResults = $this->testAndFixResultsIfDBGoneAway($sql, $params);
        if($newResults != false){
            $results = $newResults;
        }
    }

    return $results;
}

function isConnected(){
    $db = db::getDB($this->_database);

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT 'foo' AS test");
    $query->execute();

    $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    //we aren't connected if we get no response
    if($results == array()){
        return false;
    }

    //if there is a response, return true
    return true;
}


function testAndFixResultsIfDBGoneAway($sql, $params){
    if($this->isConnected()){
        return false;
    }

    //recreates the db connection in the db connection class
    db::connect($this->_database);

    $results = $this->execute($sql, $params, true);

    return $results;
}
```

I've noticed that my connection goes away, I can restart it successfully, then the next query can fail, and I can repeat this process many times, until the offending queries are done, then everything starts working normally, again.

I REALLY want to know how queries kill my database connection, so I can stop it from happening so I don't have to do a check after every query that returns no results.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the PDO error-handling mode to use exceptions should make the cause immediately apparent so you don't have to hunt around and use a lot of debugging code.

```
$db = new PDO("dblib:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_DEFAULT, DB_USER, DB_PASS, [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);
```

However, you'll have to update your error-handling code [failed prepares, failed queries] to be aware of the Exceptions.

Comment: This is handled using the set attributes functionality, and there is a try catch around the execute statement... (which in my opinion is SOP). It executes without throwing an exception, but doesn't return any results for very simple queries that I can get results from in SSMS.

Comment: Only other thing I can really turn up is [this bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40639) that seems to still be open after 8+ years...

Comment: I've added more info, now that I found out after exploring the error some more.